# Visual Studio Code - Open file with folder from terminal (code)

Tags: bash, shell, automation

i'm trying to make a bash script that basically creates a new directory and opens it directly through visual studio code

i've managed to do that, however, now i want to make it automatically add a 'README.md' file, and open it **WITH** the new folder

thank you

i couldn't find anything on the internet, nor with the code help command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

solved - run:

```
code /path/to/folder/ /path/to/file/
```

[documentation for vsc cli](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)